# RestKit 0.22.0: each -[getObject] call cancels previous one (error -999)

Tags: restkit, nsurlrequest, nsoperationqueue, restkit-0.20

1. First, `getObject` with a list of IDs.
2. Then, use those IDs for multiple `getObject`s calls.

The problem is that **any one of those multiple `getObject` gets cancelled (`error -999`)**.

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

- (void)firstGetListOfIDs 
{
    A *a = [A new];
    [objectManager getObject:a
                        path:nil
                  parameters:parameters
                     success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                         for (NSString* anID in a.listOfIDs)
                             [self thenGetObjectForID:anID];
                     } failure:nil];
}

- (void)thenGetObjectForID:(NSString*)anID
{
    B *b = [B new];
    [objectManager getObject:b
                        path:nil
                 parameters:parametersWithAnID
                    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                 } failure:nil];
}
```

That is, each `getObject` call (in `thenGetObjectForID:` above) errors on lines `211` and `552` in `RKObjectRequestOperation.m`:

> E restkit.network:**RKObjectRequestOperation.m:211** GET
>   'http://domain.com/sdk/b?id=anID'
>   (0 / 0 objects) [request=0.0000s mapping=0.0000s total=0.0006s]:
>   Cancelled
>
> E restkit.network:**RKObjectRequestOperation.m:552** Object request failed:
>   Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x134772e0
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://domain.com/sdk/b?id=anID}

Now, I can remedy this by adding `[objectManager.operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];` but, alas this blocks the main thread. **How to make multiple, *asynchronous* `getObject` requests?**

I've tried using `RKObjectManager`'s `enqueueBatchOfObjectRequestOperations:progress:completion:`, though not sure if properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit turned out to be a vagabond `[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] cancelAllObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod:matchingPathPattern:];` call.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade to the latest (or at least not a pre) version of RestKit.

Generally, your code looks fine and you should be able to make multiple concurrent requests. You should set the maximum number of concurrent operations on `objectManager.operationQueue` to around 5 though or you may flood the system and all requests will timeout.

Comment: Even at `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 2` the requests "cancel" each other (`error -999`). PS. I did try upgrading to 0.22, but failed (either via CocoaPods or as a Git-submodule): 0.22 somehow breaks object-mapping. Will try 0.21 or 0.20 versions.

Comment: No luck with 0.20.3. All else being equal, upgrading from `-pre6` version breaks mapping.

Comment: Do you have a server log? It could be cancelled there. Or it could be that there is no buffer space available for the transmissions.

Comment: The mapping breaks so that incoming objects are *only* mapped to a base-class, but not (any more) to its respective sub-classes ... this then fails on a `NSAssert` which expects one of those sub-classes. The requests don't get through to the server. Is this "buffer space" something more concrete within RestKit (yes, I did search)?

Comment: We're talking about AFNetworking / NSURLConnection rather than RestKit as it's the underlying comms, not the mapping, that relates to buffer and network errors. If you limit to a single request at a time everything works?

Comment: With `[objectManager.operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];` it "works" (blocks UI) ... but doesn't work with `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1` (nothing gets through).

Comment: Sometimes `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1` returns `-999`, sometimes `200` (but no actual data is returned). As you said, RestKit needs to be first upgraded out of `-pre` version.

Comment: After realizing that the (inherited) `RestKit` code was modified (in the same commit that added `RestKit` itself!), I've successfully updated to 0.22.0. Still, the problem persists ... now I've got to figure out whether those (five) modifications are to blame (for failed `-getObject` requests).